Marten does not create snapshots
Here is the code I use to initialize marten and wolverine
using Marten;
using Marten.Events.Daemon.Resiliency;
using Marten.Events.Projections;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Oakton.Resources;
using Todos.EventSourcing.Contracts.Commands.TodoItem;
using Todos.EventSourcing.Domain.Aggregates;
using Todos.EventSourcing.Domain.CommandHandlers.TodoItem.CreateTodoItem;
using Weasel.Core;
using Wolverine;
using Wolverine.Http;
using Wolverine.Marten;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddMarten(opts =>
    {
        opts.Connection(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Postgres")!);
        opts.DatabaseSchemaName = "todos";
        opts.UseSystemTextJsonForSerialization();
        opts.UseSystemTextJsonForSerialization(enumStorage: EnumStorage.AsString);
        
        opts.Projections.Snapshot<TodoItem>(SnapshotLifecycle.Async);
        // also tried opts.Projections.Snapshot<TodoItem>(SnapshotLifecycle.Inline);
        
        if (builder.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            opts.AutoCreateSchemaObjects = AutoCreate.All;
        }
    })
    .AddAsyncDaemon(DaemonMode.HotCold)
    .IntegrateWithWolverine();

builder.Services.AddResourceSetupOnStartup();

builder.Host.UseWolverine(opts =>
{
    opts.Policies.AutoApplyTransactions();
    opts.Policies.UseDurableLocalQueues();
    opts.Discovery.IncludeAssembly(typeof(CreateTodoItemHandler).Assembly);
});

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddWolverineHttp();

var app = builder.Build();

app.MapPostToWolverine<CreateTodoItem, CreateTodoItemResult>("/todo-items");
app.MapPostToWolverine<ChangeTodoItemTitle, EmptyResult>("/todo-items/change-title");
app.MapWolverineEndpoints();

app.MapGet("/", () => Results.Redirect("/swagger"));

app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI();

app.Run();

Streams and Events are created and stored in db properly, however no snapshots are created neither if using Inline nor Async projection modes. I mean when I inspect mt_streams then for all streams snapshot column is null. I guess some misconfiguration... no errors reported from wolverine/marten.
Here is how my handler looks like:
using Todos.EventSourcing.Contracts.Events.TodoItem;
using Wolverine.Marten;

namespace Todos.EventSourcing.Domain.CommandHandlers.TodoItem.ChangeTodoItemTitle;

public static class ChangeTodoItemTitleHandler
{
    [AggregateHandler]
    public static IEnumerable<object> Handle(Contracts.Commands.TodoItem.ChangeTodoItemTitle command, Aggregates.TodoItem item)
    {
        if (command.Title != item.Title)
        {
            var evt = new TodoItemTitleChanged(command.Title);
            item.Apply(evt);
            yield return evt;
        }
    }
}

